# Why is not possible to enter text in Textbox after getting text from specific encoding?

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know how to edit text inside textbox after reading text from raw byte with specific encoding?

Only key that seems to be allowed are: Home, End, Page Up/Down, Delete...

If you try to press any key like: A-Z it won't show up, text box is behaving like Key-down event was overridden somewhere with e.Suppress set to true.

Code:
`

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        byte[] _buffer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Text = "Encoding (Test)";
            textBox1.Text = "1252"; // Western European (Windows)
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_buffer == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select file to read from!");
                buttonOpenFile_Click(null, null);
                return;
            }
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
            textBox2.Text = encoding.GetString(_buffer);
        }

        private void buttonOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var of = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (of.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Text = of.SafeFileName;
                    ReadToBuffer(of.FileName);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ReadToBuffer(string file)
        {
            using (var fileIO = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                _buffer = new byte[fileIO.Length];
                fileIO.Read(_buffer, 0, (int)fileIO.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

[Click here to download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/463b8pyraimzipy/WindowsFormsApplication1.rar?dl=0)

Comment: You mean that `textbox2` refuse to take your input ?

Comment: yeah, if you tried to enter like: a-z and few more character it won't show up

Comment: What's the type of it?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem - new characters show up for me with no problems. What's in your file?

Comment: There's nothing special about strings returned from `Encoding.GetString()`. Please create an example that reproduces the issue without any cruft.

Comment: Do you have the max size of the textbox set, and if so is the file you are opening and reading from filling up that textbox to capacity?

Comment: subtitle file .srt @jon-skeet

Comment: It doesn't help that we don't have that file... do you see the same problem if you open just a small plaintext file? I suspect you may well be hitting the maximum capacity of the textbox. If you delete some text first, can you *then* type?

Comment: just a sec @jon-skeet

Comment: [Subtitle file](http://www49.zippyshare.com/v/12k2EqGD/file.html) /cc jon-skeet

Comment: Nope, even after deleting text I'm still not able to type

Comment: What is the byte-size of that file? I am sure it is fine, but I try not to make a habit of downloading random files. Also, how much of the text did you try to delete? Only a few characters, or a large swath of it, before you started typing again?

Comment: @gmiley you can see raw text => [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Dy6kqY3y)

Comment: @gmiley Note that problem is not only with that file

Comment: Right, that is what I figured, which is why I just wanted to know the byte-size? By default TextBox.MaxLength is 32767. If your file is larger than that the issue is reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the file you are attempting to open is larger than the TextBox.MaxLength. I was able to reproduce the issue by creating a simple text file filled with random characters exceeding the MaxLength of the TextBox control.